# Can I have help interperting this code? char variable somehow storing big numbers

Tags: c++, data-type

I have this GSM module I got for my arduino project and I am trying to access the call feature, but the function makes no sense.

```
  boolean Adafruit_FONA::callPhone(char *number) {
  char sendbuff[35] = "ATD";
  strncpy(sendbuff+3, number, min(30, strlen(number)));
  uint8_t x = strlen(sendbuff);
  sendbuff[x] = ';';
  sendbuff[x+1] = 0;
  //Serial.println(sendbuff);

  return sendCheckReply(sendbuff, "OK");
  }
```

This is the function however how is char being used to display a phone number in the parameter?

Comment: This is bad code. It uses magic numbers (3, 30, and 35) instead of calculating values based on the actual sizes. The second call to `strlen` isn't needed; `x` is the sum of the length of the first string and the number of characters that were copied. Setting aside the incorrect use of `strncpy` that I mention in a comment below, if the input string is to long, the code truncates it and dials the truncated number! It shouldn't do that; it should return an error code. Don't try to learn programming from stuff like this. You'll pick up lots of bad habits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's passed as a `char*`. This can be derived from either a string literal (e.g. `"212555121"`) or from a `String` via its `c_str()` method.

Comment: so if i wanted to use the function all i have to do is enter a string with the number inside?

Comment: If you want to use a fixed string then you can call it with the literal. If you have a `char*` with the string then you can pass it directly. If you have a `String` then you need to call the `c_str()` method. [Arduino string reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/string)

Comment: can u give an example of how i would create the char* with the string

Comment: What's wrong with how your posted code does it (other than that fiasco with `strncpy()`, of course)?

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple:

`char *number;` a variable pointing to a character (or string of them).
`char sendbuff[35];` 35 characters in a row, making a string.
The first 3 chars at locatiion sendbuff are initialised to "A", "T", & "D", then the string at "number" is copied to it (to a maximum of 30 characters, by taking the lesser of the length of "number" or 30. This is important to avoid over-running the space allocated.
This string of characters gets sent out; & a check is made for an "O" & a "K"

If you don't 'get' pointers, you need to look it up, as it's pretty central stuff.

Comment: I don't know why `strncpy` has become so popular as a "safe" replacement for `strcpy`. It isn't. If the number string is longer than 30 characters `strncpy` will copy the first 30 characters and stop **without adding a NUL terminator**. The subsequent call to `strlen` can then run off the end of the buffer, and if that happens, the two bytes subsequently stored will go outside the buffer.